# Why won't Magento layout load

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am currently trying to replicate my IndexController to a BetaController. I want Beta to use the same template files as Index and I thought I have it correct in the layout xml file, but apparently it is not working correctly.

I know the Beta controller is working correctly since I can output text from the controller.

Here is my layout xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <searchengine_index_index>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="searchengine" template="searchengine/searchengine.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </searchengine_index_index>

    <searchengine_beta_index>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="searchengine" template="searchengine/searchengine.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </searchengine_beta_index>

</layout>
```

Basically what I did was created a new block called searchengine_beta_index and copied and pasted the contents from searchengine_index_index. Is this wrong? Should I have done something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok fixed it myself. Forgot to flush the cache.

Comment: Ok to be more specific, I flushed ALL the caches in the admin panel, however I probably could have just flushed the Layouts cache.